# Set Multiple Worksheets Tab Name to Follow Each Worksheet's Cell A1

Tags: excel

Is there any way (e.g. less loading on Excel) for me to set all worksheets' tab name will follow automatically the value of cell A1 in each worksheet? so, when I create Hyperlink that direct user to another sheet, changing cell name will face no issue on hyperlink.

Comment: So what method gives more loading on excel?

Comment: As I have a lot of worksheet with same formulas, the file becomes bulky, just try to see if any optimal solution. Firstly, would like to know if there is a way to set multiple worksheets to follow cell value in each worksheet. Thanks.